# ActiveRecord migration - when reversible.up/reversible.down feature was introduced?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

I'm currently in the process of upgrading old legacy Rails app and trying to find the exact version number when this `reversible.up`, `reversible.down` block feature was introduced.

```ruby
class SplitNameMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :first_name, :string
    add_column :users, :last_name, :string

    reversible do |dir|
      User.reset_column_information
      User.all.each do |u|
        dir.up   { u.first_name, u.last_name = u.full_name.split(' ') }
        dir.down { u.full_name = "#{u.first_name} #{u.last_name}" }
        u.save
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[4.0.0](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/activerecord/CHANGELOG.md#rails-400-june-25-2013) it was.

> New method `reversible` makes it possible to specify code to be run when migrating up or down. See the [Guide on Migration](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/guides/source/migrations.md#using-the-reversible-method)

Comment: @BenFenner good point. I've slightly adjusted the question to make it less confusing. I was looking for `reversible` method/feature version number, to be exact.